# How to remove dropped item from control where item was dragged from

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, itemtemplate

I'm trying to remove an Object of type Order from an listview which is sent from another listview in the same listview control. The xaml for these listviews is like this:

```
 <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="448" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="664" Margin="121,43,-2,0">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="100"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Button x:Name="Up" Content="^" Click="Up_Click"/>
                        <Button x:Name="Down" Content="v" Click="Down_Click"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Chauffeur.Naam}" Width="50"/>
                        <ListView x:Name="Swagnek" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" Height="50" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="ListView_DragEnter" PreviewDragOver="ListView_PreviewDragOver" Drop="ListView_Drop">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="HoiDoei" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding ID}" MouseRightButtonDown="HoiDoei_MouseRightButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonDown="HoiDoei_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

So I'm trying to drag and drop orders between two listviews.
The problem is that when I've dropped it I have to remove the drag and dropped order from the listview where I dragged it from.

I'm using this c# code.

```
       private void ListView_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {

                var tb = (TextBlock)sender;
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, (Order)tb.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }

   private void ListView_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Move;
        }

        private void ListView_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void ListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            var lv = sender as ListView;
            if (lv.ItemsSource == null)
                lv.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
            var order = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Order)) as Order;
            var items = lv.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Order>;
            items.Add(order);
            orderlist.Remove(order);
        }
```

It's also possible to drag from an listbox to one of the listviews(not included in the code)

That's why

```
 orderlist.Remove(order);
```

is in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ItemsSource property of the ListView that you drag the object *from* should also be set or bound to an `ObservableCollection<Order>`. Then you should just be able to remove the dropped item from this collection once you have a reference to it:

```
ObservableCollection<Order> _source;
private void ListView_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    var tb = (TextBlock)sender;
    ListView parentListView = FindParent<ListView>(tb);
    if (parentListView != null)
        _source = parentListView.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Order>;
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, (Order)tb.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

public static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}

private void ListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var lv = sender as ListView;
    if (lv.ItemsSource == null)
        lv.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
    var order = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Order)) as Order;
    var items = lv.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Order>;
    items.Add(order);
    orderlist.Remove(order);
    if (_source != null && _source.Contains(order))
        _source.Remove(order);
}
```

Comment: You're the best, thanks for the little explanation too, makes me feel like I learned something :)

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing the TextBlock's DataContext in as the data to the DragAndDrop action pass the TextBlock itself.

```
    private void ListView_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, (TextBlock)sender, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```

Then in the drop handler you can now get access to the ItemsControl (via static helper methods) which contains the TextBlock, and using the ItemsControl you can get the underlying ItemsSource collection.

```
    private void ListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var lv = (ListView)sender;
        if (lv.ItemsSource == null)
        {
            lv.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
        }

        var tb = (TextBlock)e.Data.GetData(typeof(TextBlock));
        var order = (Order)tb.DataContext;

        var container = ItemsControl.ContainerFromElement(null, tb);
        var control = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(container);
        (control.ItemsSource as ICollection<Order>)?.Remove(order);

        (lv.ItemsSource as ObservableCollection<Order>)?.Add(order);

        orderlist.Remove(order);
    }
```

That will remove the dragged order from the ItemsControl which it was originally contained within.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your answer. The problem is that it crashes when I'm  dragging an order from the listbox because order is null

Comment: Kevin, would you be able to post the XAML for the ListBox and C# code for the handler that initiates the drag operation from the ListBox?